# Unity/Oculus Quest (Android) Playing .ogg/.mp3 causes errors in the logcat [AndroidVideoMedia::DecodeAudio|NdkMediaCodec]

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, audio, android-mediacodec, oculusquest

I have .ogg and .mp3 files in my Assets/Resources folder. Audio files play well. But playing any of them using the Audio Source component results in hundreds of error messages appearing in the log. I tried different audio files with same result.

Unfortunately I could not find the cause or solution to this problem. If you have an idea please help.

[image: mp3 file codec info]
[image: ogg file code info]
[image: unity inspector audio clip]
[image: unity inspector audio source]
[image: logcat]

```
20:08:40.813 Unity AndroidVideoMedia::DecodeAudio got unexpected buffer (-10000) for media track 0
20:08:40.813 NdkMediaCodec sf error code: -38
20:08:40.813 NdkMediaCodec sf error code: -38
```